# What is the equivalent of a device context in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a requirement to develop a custom set of UI controls such as graphs, charts, etc using vanilla Java script. Use of Frameworks such as react, angular is not allowed. I need to know options we have to do this.

Around 14 years back I used to write custom controls using MFC using C++. The usual way to write custom drawing code was to use a device context which allows us to draw various primitives such as rectangles, text, circles, etc directly on screen.this gives us extreme flexibility to write what ever we like. Is something like this possible in JS that runs on a browser? How are existing controls uses in a browser written?

Comment: CSS, SVG or canvas can be used. Form controls are native elements
https://www.networkworld.com/article/2196344/html5-in-the-browser--canvas--video--audio--and-graphics.html

Comment: better you purchase UI Themes, there are plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

> How are existing controls uses in a browser written?

With a combination of native (i.e. using APIs not exposed to client-side code) code and CSS.

> The usual way to write custom drawing code was to use a device context which allows us to draw various primitives such as rectangles, text, circles, etc directly on screen.this gives us extreme flexibility to write what ever we like. Is something like this possible in JS that runs on a browser?

Generally you should use a native control (like a `<button>` or `<input>`) whenever possible. Apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

If that isn't possible, then the next best option is usually [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) in combination with [`tabindex` (for keyboard accessibility)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/tabindex) and [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) to describe semantics.

There is also [the `<canvas>` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) for less vector-based stuff.